# Is it possible to use Spearman Rank Correlation to analyze two time series that exhibit cyclic behavior

Tags: correlation, time-series

I am extremely new to statistics so pardon me if this question is really easy to answer. I am trying to analyze two time series that should be physically related (wind speed and temperature). Since both time series are cyclic, I figured that a linear correlation technique like Pearson would not work and instead something that studies the monotonic relationship of the data would be better. However, from my understanding Spearman would require the sorting of data to assign ranks which would remove the cyclic behavior of both time series.

Is it possible to study the monotonic correlation between both time series without having to sort the data?

Comment: *Possible* in that you can physically carry it out, sure. Sensible? not in general, no. For example, you should be aware of the possibility of spurious correlation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_relationship#Examples . Note also that even in the absence of that sort of issue, the usual forms of inference for Spearman correlation (tests, CIs etc) relies on independence.  To be honest this sounds like an XY problem -- what would you be using this correlation to achieve, exactly? I think good answers would rely on knowing that.

Comment: @Glen_b I was trying to study the correlation between wind speed and the temperature of a component in a wind turbine, in the hope to set get a basis of normal temperature jumps at wind speeds, so that eventually I can use it to check if the component is overheating abnormally compared to historical data.

Comment: " set get a basis of normal temperature jumps at wind speeds, so that eventually I can use it to check if the component is overheating abnormally compared to historical data" ... this doesn't sound like a good use case for Spearman correlation at all.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No, that won't work.

Longer answer: If I were new to statistics, I would not try to analyze time series on my own.  In fact, even though I did data analysis for 25 years, I would not try to do time series on my own. It is very tricky and very easy to go wrong. If a client came to me with a time series problem, I would not take it on.

For one thing, cyclic data are not monotonic. "Monotonic" means constantly increasing or decreasing. For another, when you have two variables that are closely related to time, it is extremely easy to find spurious correlations.

For instance, if you plot sales of ice cream and shark attacks over time, you will find a strong correlation.  Or the Dow Jones with the number of cell phones. Or all sorts of things.

I suggest you either hire a consultant or, if you are at a university, find a colleague in the statistics department who can help you for co-authorship on a paper.

Comment: +1, although I think that by "monotonic", OP is referring to the relationship between the two series, not the behavior of a single series over time.

Comment: Cyclic data aren't monotonic, but the relationship between two cyclic variables may be. I don't see much issue in how the OP is using the term.

Comment: Maybe you are both right about what OP meant, but I'm not so sure. The reason they give for not wanting Pearson's is that the data are cyclic.

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I used monotonic, I was trying to figure out if the data points from one time series changes by the same magnitude as the other time series, which I assumed would be considered monotonic. I could be wrong in the terminology I used so I apologize for the confusion caused.